# Tags page in jekyll site working locally but not on GitHub pages, gives 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404, jekyll, github-pages

Wanted to create a "tags page" that has all posts with a certain tag. I added it to the header of my website but I keep getting a 404 error. It looks like the tags page isn't building at all?

404 Error page:
https://tiffanychenster.github.io/personal-blog/tag/reviews/

Repo:
https://github.com/tiffanychenster/personal-blog

Confused as to why it works locally but not on Github pages. Thought it might be an error with my nav links but messed around with header.html a lot and got nowhere. Any help with creating the tag page on remote server would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

GitHub Pages only allows you to run a number of whitelisted plugins, and `jekyll-tagging` is not one of them. This means the plugin won't run, the tag pages won't exist and you'll get a 404 response.

The suggested workaround if you want to continue using GitHub Pages and custom plugins is to build the site locally and commit the output. You could commit it to the same repo in a subfolder and then select that folder as your base in GitHub. Alternatively, you could keep the result in a separate repo (i.e. `my-website` and `my-website-output`). This way the source git history isn't tied to your output - as well as keeping each repo's file size down.

Another way altogether would be to create the tag pages without the plugin. It would be a bit more manual but not always unmaintainable depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the ruby gem update_tags](https://github.com/pachun/update_tags), which does what you're looking for and works in GitHub pages.

[Here's some more context about how and why that gem works](https://pachulski.me/jekyll-blog-post-tags-and-github-pages).